# Magento2 - Change placeholder size at product edit

Tags: magento2, product, adminhtml, product-attribute

We have magento 2.1.9ce.

And we need to add a lot of new products in the next few weeks>
That's why I would like to easy up some little things.

There are 2 attributes when making the product where I would lik eto change the placeholder size.

Current situation:
[image]
When I inspect the code I can change the place holder size to:

```
<select multiple="" class="admin__control-multiselect" data-bind="
    attr: {
        name: inputName,
        id: uid,
        size: size ? size : '6',
        disabled: disabled,
        'aria-describedby': noticeId,
        placeholder: placeholder
    },
    hasFocus: focused,
    optgroup: options,
    selectedOptions: value,
    optionsValue: 'value',
    optionsText: 'label'" name="product[kleur]" id="HL7HO0G" size="17" aria-describedby="notice-HL7HO0G" placeholder="">
```

and:

```
<select multiple="" class="admin__control-multiselect" data-bind="
    attr: {
        name: inputName,
        id: uid,
        size: size ? size : '6',
        disabled: disabled,
        'aria-describedby': noticeId,
        placeholder: placeholder
    },
    hasFocus: focused,
    optgroup: options,
    selectedOptions: value,
    optionsValue: 'value',
    optionsText: 'label'" name="product[soort]" id="A4PDRTU" size="12" aria-describedby="notice-A4PDRTU" placeholder="">
```

That gives this wanted result:

[image]

Now I can select much faster all the right options.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

For now i have changed the default=6 to a larger number.

Now all Selectboxes are changed. this can you do in `vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Form/Element/MultiSelect.php`

here you can change it to any number you like:

```
const DEFAULT_SIZE = 6;
```